# Questioning the plural form on this sentence

Tags: phrases, grammatical-number

I wrote:

> Would 7 pm **work** for you?

My editor corrected me:

> Would 7 pm **works** for you?

English is not my first language, but I can't get around the sound of the plural *works* in the sentence. Is it correct?

Would it be correct if I write:

> Does 7 pm **work** for you?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be editing your editor. Both *Would 7 pm work for you?* and *Does 7 pm work for you?* are correct. *Would 7 pm works for you?* is incorrect.

Comment: *Works*  here is a verb, so it's actually third person *singular*. When the verb has an accompanying auxiliary (like *would* or *does*), the plain form (the one found in the infinitive) is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You should use "work" in the sentence. It depends on where it is in the sentence. An easy way to tell which form is correct is by looking at similar sentences. 
Does Ted fly? Ted flies.
Does 7pm work for you? Seven works for me.

Comment: Totally agree. Would / Does 7pm work for you? Yes, 7pm works for me.